# Как разместить картинку полностью в блоке

Tags: html, css

Как разместить большую картинку (большая высота и ширина) в блоке с небольшой высотой и шириной (параметры блоку не задаются), чтобы она нормально выглядела?

Comment: Как вариант указать для изоображения ширину  100%. Пример: `<img src="image.png" width="100%">`. Я правильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вот здесь можно найти нужную вам информацию: [ссылка](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: Когда указываю ширину 100%, картинка сильно расстягивается и не помещается по высоте в блок. Как можно сделать так, чтобы она поместилась в блок целиком ?

Comment: При указании `width="100%" ` высота изображения автоматически увеличивается пропорционально ширине. Можно задать высоту вручную, тем самым подогнав изображение под нужные размеры вашего блока, но тогда может само изображение перекоситься (не пропорционально растянется). Попробуй указать `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;`. Пример как это работает можно посмотреть здесь:   [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xwrvxser/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, если через background-image задавал картинку, то через правило

```
background-size:cover;
```

если задавал в верстке через `img`, то просто `width:100%;`
по идее так